# Trigger for insert table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have sql server 2005 and need to create trigger for insert query.

I have Table naemd as "Log" with column named as UserID,UserName,LogDate,LogTime and want to transfer data into other table named as "DataTable" with same column name.

I have created trigger

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Transfer] on [dbo].[Log]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

insert into DataTable (UserID,UserName,LogDate,LogTime)

SELECT UserID,UserName,LogDate,LogTime 
FROM Log where UserID not in(select UserID from DataTable)

END
```

New Data is updated on daily basis in "Log" table and so i want to transfer new data from Log table to DataTable with trigger.Execution time is very high and so no output .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

you have "inserted" table in trigger, so you can insert data from it

```
insert into DataTable (UserID, UserName, LogDate, LogTime)
select UserID, UserName, LogDate, LogTime 
from inserted
```

Comment: Yes, selecting from the base table will insert ALL rows EVERY time, not just NEW rows. This could EASILY explain long execution times. 
I'm willing to bet dollars to donuts you really need to change INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM LOG to INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM INSERTED .

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger definition, you should be using the `inserted` table, which contains all the rows added to the Log Table.

Comment: join is not needed in his case :)

Comment: If he's simply looking to insert new rows period, as an audit log so to speak, there is no need for a join, just a straight SELECT ... FROM INSERTED .